# MKMapView & iOS6, avoid instant update of the map

Tags: mkmapview, caeagllayer

I have implemented an application that use `MKMapView` to show satellite map. In my application I need to update the center of the map programmatically together with the transform of the map view. Before iOS 6, this works well. On iOS 6, the two-step operations cannot be joined anymore. That is, when I try to set the map center, it will be immediately refreshed, before I have the opportunities to set the transformation. This is bad because, for an instant, I can see the intermediate representation. Looking inside the new `MKMapView`implementation, I see that now it use OpenGL:

`VKMapCanvas: 0x9d29440; frame = (0 0; 1217.57 1217.57); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = [CAEAGLLayer]: 0x9d2a610`

I think the problem is that the OpenGL surface is updated immediately. My question is, there's anyway to enable/disable the update of the `VKMapCanvas`?